# Retrieving flagged messages with webklex php-imap

Tags: laravel, php-imap

I 'm trying to fetch flagged mails from a specified folder.
I tried:

```
$folder->query()->not()->unflagged()->setFetchBody(false)->leaveUnread()->get();

$folder->query()->not()->where([["UNFLAGGED"]])->leaveUnread()->get();
```

And some other I don't have now.

It throws me this reponse:

> Too few arguments to function
> Webklex\PHPIMAP\Query\WhereQuery::where(), 0 passed and at least 1
> expected

Also tried:

```
$folder->query()->flagged('Flagged')->setFetchBody(false)->leaveUnread()->get();
```

This throws me:

> Webklex \PHPIMAP\ Exceptions\ImapServerErrorException

I also tried:

```
$aMessage = $folder->query()->seen()->setFetchBody(false)->leaveUnread()->get();
$aMessage = $folder->query()->unseen()->setFetchBody(false)->leaveUnread()->get();
$aMessage = $folder->query()->unflagged()->setFetchBody(false)->leaveUnread()->get();
$aMessage = $folder->query()->whereAll()->setFetchBody(false)->leaveUnread()->get();
```

And they work perfectly.

Any ideas why I can not retrieve flagged messages or where is my error?